# Standard conformity of a solution to a namespace/ADL thing

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, std, argument-dependent-lookup

Hello insiders of the standard,

I want to read pairs of numbers from a file into a std::map and use code like the appended one.  Now, it works but I have a couple of questions on how reliable it is.

My main problem is in the two lines marked with (*).  Here the templates (i/o)stream_iterator<...> get instantiated.  Within them code like (#)

```
std::pair<int, int> x;
some_istream >> x; // (##)
```

gets created where the line with (##) actually calls an operator of signature

```
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, std::pair<int, int> & v);
```

Now ADL comes on place and decides where to look for the operator >>.  It considers the current namespace and the namespaces of all arguments.  Now since all arguments live in namespace std and the code (#) itself also lives in std (it gets instanciated within that namespace as the template is defined there), std is the only namespace considered at all.  So I definately must make my operator available in that namespace somehow, don't I?

Unfortunatelly, I'm not allowed to put new symbols into the namespace std (I heared so).  So I looked for the least invasive way to archive my goal anyway.  I found I can just put my operator in my own namespace and announce it to the std namespace (see (**)) in the implementation file where I use it (that's where I use the templates (*)).

So here are my questions:

- Am I "allowed" to do this?  At least gcc does not add a new symbol to the std namespace.
- Is it "safe" to do this?  Having (**) only in the implementation file can't corrupt any code in other files, does it?
- Is the end of the implementation file the "right" place to do it or do I need to move (**) to (***), i.e. before the use of the template that needs the operator?  At least for gcc and vc it works.  I suspect the code from template instanciation is virtually written to the end of the file after (**) so it works.  Is this defined behaviour or just implementation defined?

Thanks,

imix

---

Code:

my_io.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

namespace my {
    std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, std::pair<int, int> & v);
    std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, std::pair<int, int> const & v);
    std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, std::map<int, int> & m);
    std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, std::map<int, int> const & m);
}
```

io.cpp

```
#include "my_io.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace my {
    using namespace std;

    istream & operator >> (istream & is, pair<int, int> & v) {
        return is >> v.first >> v.second;
    }

    ostream & operator << (ostream & os, pair<int, int> const & v) {
        return os << v.first << ": " << v.second;
    }

    // (***)

    istream & operator >> (istream & is, map<int, int> & m) {
        using It = istream_iterator<pair<int, int>>;
        auto it_begin = It(is); // (*)
        auto it_end = It();
        auto it_insert = inserter(m, m.begin());
        copy(it_begin, it_end, it_insert);
        return is;
    }

    ostream & operator << (ostream & os, map<int, int> const & m) {
        auto it = ostream_iterator<pair<int, int>>(os, "\n"); // (*)
        copy(m.begin(), m.end(), it);
        return os;
    }
}

namespace std { // (**)
    using my::operator >>;
    using my::operator <<;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "my_io.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace my {
    void work() {
        string input = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
        istringstream is(input);
        map<int, int> m;
        is >> m;
        cout << m;
    }
}

int main() {
    my::work();
    return 0;
}
```

***EDIT:*** Solution (see Jonathan Walkley's answer)

The following wrapper type will solve the problem:

```
template <typename Key, typename T>
struct wrapped_pair {
    std::pair<Key, T> x;
    wrapped_pair(std::pair<Key const, T> x = std::pair<Key const, T>()) : x(x) { }
    operator std::pair<Key const, T> () const { return x; }
};
```

I tried it with a wrapper type before, but I got the `const`'s in the implicit conversions wrong.  Now, this is a working solution to my problem:

my_io.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, std::map<int, int> & m);
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, std::map<int, int> const & m);
```

my_io.cpp:

```
#include "my_io.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct wrapped_pair {
    pair<int, int> x;
    wrapped_pair(pair<int const, int> x = pair<int const, int>()) : x(x) { }
    operator pair<int const, int>() const { return x; }
};

istream & operator >> (istream & is, wrapped_pair & v) {
    return is >> v.x.first >> v.x.second;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, wrapped_pair const & v) {
    return os << v.x.first << ": " << v.x.second;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & is, map<int, int> & m) {
    using It = istream_iterator<wrapped_pair>;
    copy(It(is), It(), inserter(m, m.begin()));
    return is;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, map<int, int> const & m) {
    auto it = ostream_iterator<wrapped_pair>(os, "\n");
    copy(m.begin(), m.end(), it);
    return os;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "my_io.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
    istringstream is(input);
    map<int, int> m;
    is >> m;
    cout << m;
    return 0;
}
```

I know, I'm still hijacking the operators `>>` and `<<` for `std::map` but I leave it here for simplicity.

Comment: You defined the operators in the `my` namespace, and you use them from the `my` namespace (the `work` function is in that namespace), and you say yourself that "[i]t considers the current namespace..." In the `my::work` function the current namespace is `my`, the same namespace where the operators are overloaded, so it should work without needing to put anything in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There it works, that's right.  But it doesn't work in the lines marked ( * ) where a template from std gets instatiated.  Try remove the block marked ( ** ) and you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour to add those declarations to namespace `std`, and ADL won't find operators in namespace `my` if none of the types are associated with that namespace.

A better solution is to define your own wrapper/tag type and read into that. You can overload `operator>>` for your own type in your own namespace without problems.

```
std::pair<int, int> x;
some_istream >> my::IntPair{x};
```

The `IntPair` type doesn't need to do anything fancy:

```
namespace my {
  struct IntPair {
    std::pair<int, int>& v;
  };

  inline std::istream&
  operator>>(std::istream& in, IntPair&& ip)
  { return is >> ip.v.first >> ip.v.second; }
}
```

This is not undefined, and is also more "polite" because it doesn't hijack `operator>>` for types you don't own. You didn't write `std::pair<int, int>` so you shouldn't get to decide how stream extraction works for it. You did write `IntPair` so you can make it do whatever you want.

You can generalize this to work for other types that you don't "own":

```
namespace my {

  // write functions (not operators) to extract the types you care about:

  inline std:::istream&
  do_xtract(std::istream& in, std::pair<int, int>& v)
  { return is >> v.first >> v.second; }

  inline std:::istream&
  do_xtract(std::istream& in, std::map<int, int>& v)
  { /* ... */ }

  // write a generic wrapper that can invoke those functions:

  template<typename T>
    struct Xtractor {
      T& v;
    }

  template<typename T>
    inline Xtractor<T>
    xtract(T& t)
    { return { v }; }

  template<typename T>
    inline std:::istream&
    operator>> (std::istream& in, Xtract<T>&& x)
    { return do_xtract(in, x); }

}
```

Now you can do:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
std::cin >> my::xtract(m);
```

A completely different solution would be to use `std::map<my::WrappedInt, int>` where `WrappedInt` is a trivial struct that holds an `int` and has overloaded operators. Now you can define `my::operator>>(std::istream&, std::pair<my::WrappedInt, int>&)` and `my::operator>>(std::istream&, std::map<my::WrappedInt, int>&)` and they will be found by ADL, because `my` is an associated namespace of those types.

Comment: Oh, damn.  I tried it first with the wrapper type but it didn't work.  I got the key wrong, it's const!, i.e. the `value_type` of a `map` is `pair<Key const, T>`.  I fixed my question to explain that a little bit more.